# Inner and Nested Classes

Tags: java

Oracle documentation(in below link) says that:

> Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members
>   of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private.

But in below example I created an object `objin` (of inner class) and it couldn't access any of the method or variable of its enclosing outer class. Below is the code, could you any one clarify on the same?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

```
package Package_1;
public class Outer {

    int k;
    public void Multiply()
    {
        System.out.println("inside outer class' method multiply");
    }

    public class Inner {
        int l;
        public void Division()
        {
            System.out.println("inside inner class' method Divison");
        }

    }
}
```

Class with Main method

```
package Package_1;

public class D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer objout = new Outer();
        objout.k = 5;
        objout.Multiply();

        Outer.Inner objin = objout.new Inner();
        objin.l = 7;
        objin.Division();          
    }
}
```

With `objin` object I couldn't access that `Multiple` method in its enclosing class.

Comment: @VigneshVino: yes, he has one.

Answer (score 5):

### I see your "privates"!

From the code of the non-static nested class (inner class) you have access to both public and private members of the enclosing class.

[image]

### But it's *your* "privates", not mine!

This is what you're thinking when you try do `objin.Multiply()`: you are accessing `Multiply()` as though it's a **member** of the inner class, but it's not. Remember, you can see it from within the code of the inner class, but it will not be exposed as though it's yours.

[image]

Comment: I like your very "visual" style. What tool are you using for those?

Answer (score 2):

This is what the specification says

```
public class Outer{
   private int x;
   private void method(){
   }
   public void publicMethod(){} 

   public class Inner{

      //has access to even private properties of x
      method(); //can be called

      //NOTE: Only has ACCESS and does not INHERIT those methods
   }

}
```

What you are trying is to access the `publicMethod()` with the instance of `Inner`, which does not have any method of that name.

***THE CRUX:***

The non-static nested classes ***just has the access*** to all properties and methods of container class, but ***does not inherit*** those methods.

`objin.Multiply()` cannot work as the crux explains that `Multiply()` is defined on `Outer` and not `Inner`, so there is no method `Multiply()` on `Inner`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't say that you can access to fields and methods of the outer class by using a reference to the inner class. So you can't do

```
objin.Multiply();
```

because Multiply is not a method of Inner. What you can do is:

```
public class Inner {
    int l;
    public void Division()
    {
        System.out.println("I can access the field k in outer: " + k);
        System.out.println("I can access the method Multiply in outer (even if Multiply was private): ");
        Multiply();
        // which is a shortcut for
        Outer.this.Multiply();
    }
}
```

PS: please respect the Java naming conventions. Methods start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the method by using instance of the Inner class object. It can be accessed outside only by Outer class method. You can call the method inside the class definition of the Inner class directly but not by using the instance of inner class. if you still want to do this try :

```
package Package_1;
public class Outer {

int k;
public void Multiply()
{
    System.out.println("inside outer class' method multiply");
}

public class Inner {
    int l;
    public void Division()
    {
        System.out.println("inside inner class' method Divison");
    }

    public void Multiply() {
         Outer.this.Multiply();  //Outer class method.
    }

}
}
```

Comment: That will cause a StackOverflowError.

Comment: Why is it giving stack overflow?

Comment: I got it. I need to use Outer.this.Multiply();

Comment: I'm sorry, am bit confused, as per object oriented concepts in Java, we can call a method with its object reference or with class name(in case of static methods). But, how in this case we can just call a method alone - "Multiple():" - inside another method. Will this not contradict the java fundamentals.

Comment: Outer.this holds the current Outer object reference. So it is not a static call to Multiply()